# Appcelerator Titanium json mysql tableview

Tags: php, mysql, json, appcelerator

How do I get this into a tableviewRow which then goes into a tableview? :

```
sendit.open('GET', 'http://redirect.intocept.com/read.php');  

sendit.send(); 
sendit.onload = function(){  

var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  

var json = json.lystsejler;  

var dataArray = [];  
var pos;  
var theheader = 0;
for( pos=0; pos < json.length; pos++){  
    var firstletter = json[pos].navn[0];
    if (theheader==0){
        theheader = firstletter;
        data.push({title:'' + json[pos].navn + Math.floor(Distance(latitude, longitude, json[pos].lat, json[pos].lng)) +' sømil',  header:''+firstletter+'',  hasChild:true, test:json[pos].navn, billedeupload:json[pos].billedeupload,billede1:json[pos].billede1, billede2:json[pos].billede2, billede3:json[pos].billede3,});};
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what @rajesh.adhi said; assuming your response will be structured something like this:

```
{
    array:[
        {title:'FOO'},
        {title:'BAR'}
    ]
}
```

Then your code for generating the table view rows should look like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);  
var data = [];  

for( var i=0; i < json.length; i++){  
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title: json.array[i].title
    });
    data.push(row);
}

tableView.setData(data);
```

Comment: This is also assuming that you have already created the tableView.